# Changing community/collection title in DSpace

Tags: dspace

I have a question regarding one community/collection view. Can anyone tell me the name of the XSL file where I can change the way the title is being written? I went through most of the files and I don't see the part where the title can be changed. I would like to add some information underneath it.

For example, in demo, it would be "Test1" in this page: http://demo.dspace.org/xmlui/handle/10673/9.

Thanks ahead,
Anja

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Mirage theme, it would be 
[in community-view.xsl](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-4_x/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/themes/dri2xhtml-alt/aspect/artifactbrowser/community-view.xsl) and in [collection-view.xsl](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-4_x/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/themes/dri2xhtml-alt/aspect/artifactbrowser/collection-view.xsl)

However the title is rendered [in common.xsl](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-4_x/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/themes/dri2xhtml-alt/aspect/artifactbrowser/common.xsl#L106)

Those xsl files are indirectly imported in [Mirage.xsl](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-4_x/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/themes/Mirage/Mirage.xsl#L29) through [dri2xhtml-alt/dri2xhtml.xsl](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-4_x/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/themes/dri2xhtml-alt/dri2xhtml.xsl#L43) and [artifactbrowser/artifactbrowser.xsl](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-4_x/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/themes/dri2xhtml-alt/aspect/artifactbrowser/artifactbrowser.xsl#L41-42).
Quite a way to go, but you can keep it simpler by overriding the templates in your own theme.